Blazor Hybrid .apk application works with gRPC in Debug mode but gives error in Release mode
My Blazor Hybrid application has a login screen. When user enters his data and taps a button, the data is sent to the server via gRPC service.
When the application runs in Debug mode I see no errors and successfully sign in into my account.
But in Release mode I get the .apk file. I install it on my Android device and when try to login I get the error
Status(
StatusCode="Unavailable", 
Detail="Error starting gRPC call.
HttpRequestException: Permission denied (<domain-name:port>).
SocketException: Permission denied",
DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Permission denied (<domain-name:port>)")

And I see no log in the terminal of the server, so I guess the request not even being sent.

What might cause such bizarre behaviour?

What is the difference between Release and Debug modes in Visual Studio?


UPDATE: It happens both on my physical Android device and Android emulator.

I finally found a solution!
I just simply needed to add this line to AndroidManifest.xml file (which is located in Platforms > Android folder of .NET MAUI project
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

